# Como crear Multilistas

Tags: c++

Quisiera saber si hay una forma de crear listas a partir de una lista principal.

Es decir cada lista teniendo un inicio y un final entre los cuales podemos insertar nodos. En la lista principal abajo de un nodo insertar otra lista con su inicio y su final. ¿Hay algún algoritmo que me pueda ayudar o código?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el siguiente [enlace](https://blog.martincruz.me/2012/10/listas-enlazadas-simples-en-c.html) de Martin Cruz podrás encontrar un **ejemplo** que implementa una **lista enlazada simple** de enteros (lista principal como tu dices).

Básicamente lo que hace es crear una clase llamada nodo que contiene un entero y un puntero enlace (*sgte) hacia el siguiente nodo. Es lo que puedes ver en la siguiente figura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Bien, **partiendo de dicho código**, podemos modificar la estructura inicial:

```
struct nodo{
       int nro;        // en este caso es un numero entero
       struct nodo *sgte;
};
```

Para **obtener algo como lo que muestra esta segunda imagen**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**La estructura resultante** podría ser algo como esto:

```
struct nodo{
       int nro;        // en este caso es un numero entero
       struct nodo *sgte;
       struct nodo *inf;
};
```

La modificación de las demás acciones te las dejo como deberes, no parece muy complicado.

PD: Tratandose de C++ sería interesante, a partir de dicho ejemplo, crear una **clase que podría llamarse lista enlazada 2D**. Por otro lado, en lugar de un entero la estructura podría tener cualquier tipo de objeto.

Saludos.

Comment: Muchas David ha sido de grab ayuda el aporte que me has dado! La mejor respuesta! Se parace a la lista doblemente enlazada

Comment: Me alegra que te haya servido de ayuda. Gracias.